# Redux filter not working in sync with searchbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am writing a filter function for a shopping cart app. The issues I am facing are:

1. How can I use the same filter function for a multiple checkbox filter, needs suggestion on how to go about it
2. The filter works with one keyword but doesn't work when I clear the search box(it still shows the filtered products when I clear the checkbox)

Below is my code: reducer.js

```js
import * as actionTypes from "./shopping-types";
import data from "../../data";
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  products: data,
  cart: [],
  currentItem: null,
};

const shopReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_TO_CART:
      const item = state.products.find(
        (product) => product.id === action.payload.id
      );
      console.log("hit", item);
      const inCart =
        state.cart.length === 0
          ? false
          : state.cart.find((item) =>
              item.id === action.payload.id ? true : false
            );
      console.log("hit", inCart);
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: inCart
          ? state.cart.map((item) =>
              item.id === action.payload.id
                ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 }
                : item
            )
          : [...state.cart, { ...item, qty: 1 }],
      };

    case actionTypes.REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id),
      };
    case actionTypes.INCREASE_QTY:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.map((item) =>
          item.id === action.payload.id ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 } : item
        ),
      };
    case actionTypes.DECREASE_QTY:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.map((item) =>
          item.id === action.payload.id
            ? { ...item, qty: item.qty !== 1 ? item.qty - 1 : 1 }
            : item
        ),
      };
    case actionTypes.LOAD_CURRENT_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentItem: action.payload,
      };
    case actionTypes.FILTER_PRODUCT:
      const searchParameters = data && Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...data));
      const filteredData = state.products.filter((item) =>
        searchParameters.some((parameter) =>
          item[parameter].toString().toLowerCase().includes(action.payload.toLowerCase())
        )
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        products: filteredData,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default shopReducer;
```

Nabvar.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { filterProducts } from "../../redux/Shopping/shopping-actions";

const Navbar = ({ cart, filter }) => {
  const [cartCount, setCartCount] = useState(0);
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    let count = 0;
    cart.forEach((item) => {
      count += item.qty;
    });
    setCartCount(count);
  }, [cart, cartCount]);

  const search = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSearchInput(e.target.value);
    filter(e.target.value);
  };
  
  return (
    <header>
      <nav class="bg-white border-gray-200 px-4 lg:px-6 py-2.5 dark:bg-gray-800">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center mx-auto max-w-screen-xl">
          <a class="flex items-center">
            <span class="self-center text-xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
              Teerex
            </span>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search here"
              onChange={(e) => search(e)}
            />
          </a>
          <Link to="/cart">
            <div class="flex items-center lg:order-2">
              {/* <a
              href="#"
              class="text-gray-800 dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-50 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 lg:px-5 py-2 lg:py-2.5 mr-2 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-gray-800"
            >
              Log in
            </a> */}
              <button
                href="#"
                class="text-white border-2 border-rose-500 bg-primary-700 hover:bg-primary-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 lg:px-5 py-2 lg:py-2.5 mr-2 dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-primary-800"
              >
                Cart <p className="">{cartCount}</p>
              </button>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    cart: state.shop.cart,
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    filter: (query) => dispatch(filterProducts(query)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Navbar);
```

Data.js

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Black Polo",
    "type": "Polo",
    "price": 250,
    "currency": "INR",
    "color": "Black",
    "gender": "Men",
    "quantity": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Blue Polo",
    "type": "Polo",
    "price": 350,
    "currency": "INR",
    "color": "Blue",
    "gender": "Women",
    "quantity": 3
  },
]
```

I am rendering the products data in Product.js file

Product.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addToCart } from "../../redux/Shopping/shopping-actions";
import Filter from '../Filter/Filter';
const Products = ({ products, addToCart }) => {
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState(products);
  return (
    <div className="bg-white sm:flex flex-row">
      <Filter/>
      <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl py-16 px-4 sm:py-24 sm:px-6 lg:max-w-7xl lg:px-8">
        <h2 className="sr-only">Products</h2>

        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-y-10 gap-x-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 xl:gap-x-8">
          {productData.map((product) => (
            <a key={product.id} className="group">
              <div className="aspect-w-1 aspect-h-1 w-full overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-gray-200 xl:aspect-w-7 xl:aspect-h-8">
                <img
                  src={product.imageURL}
                  alt={product.name}
                  className="h-full w-full object-cover object-center group-hover:opacity-75"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="flex flex-col">
                <h3 className="mt-4 text-sm text-gray-700">{product.name}</h3>
                <p className="mt-1 text-lg font-medium text-gray-900">
                  {product.price}
                </p>
                <button
                  onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault()
                    addToCart(product.id)}}
                  class="mt-4 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-8 rounded-full"
                >
                  Add to Cart
                </button>
              </div>
            </a>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    products: state.shop.products,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addToCart: (id) => dispatch(addToCart(id))
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Products);
```

Comment: Each time you filter you are reducing the state that is filterable. In other words, you are mutating the source of truth. Generally you want to leave the source data alone and compute the derived filtered state using the array from state and applying the filtering conditions. If you need more help from here can you [edit] the post to include where the `products` state is consumed/rendered?

Comment: @DrewReese, thanks for your response. I have included the file where products state is rendered

Comment: Sorry, I meant to also request if you could provide more of the redux code as well, at least the entirety of the state slice that reducer function is for that handles the products state.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, updated the reducer file

Comment: Well, after seeing the reducer logic it seems the `FILTER_PRODUCT` case is always filtering down the original source `data` that is imported. Each time this case runs it should "reset" and have all the data available to it to be filtered. I don't think the issue is with the filtering. Can you clarify what the issue is that you are seeing? You mention checkboxes. Have you included this code in your [mcve]?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, here is the link https://codesandbox.io/p/github/mpriyadarshini/Shopping-Cart/. I am not able to clear the filter when the search box is empty and also how can I use the same filter reducer for multi-filter checkbox on left